# Tinymce - Insert html element after inserting table

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I want to add a paragraph after every insertion of a table which will hold the table name of the table in the Tinymce plugin.
Have been able to customize the table however there is no solution to add an html element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go into the plugin folder and edit the source directly -

```
for(i='<table id="__mce"><tbody>',n=0;t>n;n++){
    for(i+="<tr>",r=0;e>r;r++)i+="<td>"+(s.ie&&s.ie<10?"&nbsp;":"<br>")+"</td>";i+="</tr>"
}
return i+="</tbody></table>"
```

Please edit this to -

```
for(i='<table id="__mce"><tbody>',n=0;t>n;n++){
    for(i+="<tr>",r=0;e>r;r++)i+="<td>"+(s.ie&&s.ie<10?"&nbsp;":"<br>")+"</td>";i+="</tr>"
}
return i+="</tbody></table><p>table name</p>"
```

This will result in "table name" getting printed in the newline.